# Themes : How can i make a Model like the Content Model with Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

I would like to have a content like the body content which contains the data of a specific content item.

To be precise, when i am using the AsideSecond Model, i want it to change on every page according to the data i entered to it, not to display the same data everywhere.

I read some discussions on Orchard Codeplex but i did not came with the exact response.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the 'AsideSecond' model? AsideSecond is a zone where you can place widgets. What do you mean by 'data of a specific content item' - do you want to show a content item in a widget, or show some information in a widget based on the content item being displayed, or something else?

Comment: _a specific content item_ is a page. I want to _show some information in a widget based on the content item being displayed_.

Answer (score 2):

You could use layers for this.

See this article here:
http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Managing-widgets.ashx

Now, you can add a layer with a rule that includes the url. So you can create a different layer for the pages you want, and add different widgets accordingly.

You could go one more step and use the [Content Tag Layer module](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NogginBox.Tagged). This will allow you to add a layer for a specific tag, then you can add different widget content based on that tag. (See how to use it [here](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/tag-layers-in-orchard))

HTH